# magento: change sender in reply contact form to customers email address

Tags: magento-1.9, email, forms

When I try to respond to a contact form on my web, although I have configured to send to `info@XXXX.com` , the sends him something like this:

```
Example:

----- Mensaje original -----
Desde: klooster@vps34324.xlshosting.net [mailto: klooster@vps34324.xlshosting.net] En nombre Comservices
Enviado el: DATE
Para: info
Asunto: Contact web


Nombre:XXXX XXXX
Correo electrónico: X.XXXX@gmail.com
Teléfono: 066-6666666
```

This is how magento sent to info@mywebsite.com the email of contact.
How can i change the from of the email?

edit: The objetive is that my email have the From: info@mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently with the server.

It makes a wrong direction, and it´s impossible to change by magento.

Comment: What do you mean by "direction"?

Comment: The conf of our email server direction.